# unit testing default method calling abstract method in an interface

Tags: java, spring-boot, junit, interface, mockito

I have an interface which has two methods - convertList and convert.

`convertList` has a default implementation that calls `convert` for each input in its inputList.

I want to write a unit test for convertList that -

- test if it calls convert method as many times as the size of inputlist
- test if it passes on convertedOutput object for each input to the list of convertedOutputs

Following is my interface -

```
public interface MyConverter {
    ConverterOutput convert(final MyDTO input, final String myParam) throws MyDTOConversionException;

    default Collection<ConverterOutput> convertList(
        final Collection<? extends MyDTO> inputList,
        final String myParam)
        throws MyDTOConversionException {
        try {
            List<ConverterOutput> converterOutputs = new ArrayList<>();

            for (MyDTO input : inputList) {
                converterOutputs.add(this.convert(input, myParam));
            }
            return converterOutputs;
        } catch (NullPointerException npe) {
            throw new MyDTOConversionException("Unable to convert dto to converter output", npe);
        }
    }
}
```

I am unable to achieve 1 while mocking the interface and stubbing its convert method. Following is my test class.

```
@SpringBootTest(classes = MyConverter.class)
public class MyConverterTest extends BaseTest {

    class MyDTOImpl extends MyDTO {
        @Override
        public void someAbstractMethod(String param) {
        }
    }

    @Mock
    private ConverterOutput converterOutput;

    @Mock
    private MyConverter myConverter;

    @Mock
    private MyDTOImpl myDTO;

    @Test
    public void testConvertListOfSizeOne() {

        String myParam = "1234";

        Collection<MyDTO> myDTOS = new ArrayList<>();
        myDTOS.add(myDTO);

        try {
            when(myConverter.convert(myDTO, myParam)).thenReturn(converterOutput);
            Collection<ConverterOutput> actualConverterOutputs = myConverter.convertList(myDTOS, myParam);

            // check if times convert method was called is as expected
            verify(myConverter, times(1)).convert(myDTO, myParam);

            // check if number of items in output object are as expected
            Assert.assertEquals(actualConverterOutputs.size(), 1);

            // check if output object is as expected
            for (ConverterOutput c: actualConverterOutputs) {
                Assert.assertSame(c, converterOutput);
            }
        } catch (MyDTOConversionException exception) {
            throw new AssertionError("MyDTOConversionException should not have occurred");
        }
    }
}
```

Following is the error I got

> Wanted but not invoked: myConverter.convert(myDTO, "1234");
>   -> at com.abc.project.converters.MyConverterTest.testConvertListOfSizeOne(MyConverterTest.java:49)
>
> However, there were other interactions with this mock:
>   myConverter.convertList(
>       [myDTO],
>       "1234" );

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Two things helped me fix the issue.

One, add an inner class that implements MyConverter interface as simply using Mock annotation seems to override the default method too and I was unable to ask Mockito to call original default method implementation.

```
class MyConverterImpl implements MyConverter {
    MyConverterImpl() {}
    @Override
    public ConverterOutput apply(final MyDTO input, final String myParam)
            throws MyDTOConversionException {
        return converterOutput;
    }
}
```

Next, explicitly ask Mockito to call the real method

```
when(myConverter.convertList(myDTOS, myParam)).thenCallRealMethod();
```

Without this, default implementation of convertList was not getting called.

Comment: @csmckelvey how did you get the nice syntax highlighting?

Comment: Added java tag to the question and indented code by 4 spaces.